# Not sure what's wrong with MySQL?

Tags: mysql

These are the instructions from HackerRank

[https://i.imgur.com/pCQTGmA.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nsRA.png)

This is my output

[https://i.imgur.com/5NLgNE7.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0Y2O.png)

This is the code I've written

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.NAME, COUNT(EMPLOYEE.ID)
FROM DEPARTMENT
JOIN EMPLOYEE ON EMPLOYEE.DEPT_ID = DEPARTMENT.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY EMPLOYEE.DEPT_ID, DEPARTMENT.NAME
ORDER BY COUNT(EMPLOYEE.ID) DESC, DEPARTMENT.NAME
```

It all honestly seems fine but it obviously isn't.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does python have to do with this?

Comment: the query doesn't return a count for *unstaffed* departments i.e, departments that would have employee count reported as zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are asking this **AFTER** having finished your test. If not shame on you :(

It seems you are missing the requirement to count departments without employees. Use a `left join` to fix that.

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.NAME, COUNT(EMPLOYEE.ID) as EMPLOYEE_COUNT
FROM DEPARTMENT
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE ON EMPLOYEE.DEPT_ID = DEPARTMENT.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY DEPARTMENT.DEPT_ID
ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_COUNT DESC, DEPARTMENT.NAME
```